# Rolling count of distinct years

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

This might be very easy but I have not yet figure it out.

This is a section of my dataset:

```
structure(list(Patent = c("4683202", "4683195", "4800159", "4965188", 
"4994368", "5328824", "4879214", "4921794", "4983728", "4994372"
), subclass = c("435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", 
"435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2"
), AppYear = c(1985L, 1986L, 1986L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1988L, 
1988L, 1990L, 1990L), app = 1:10, class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), .Names = c("Patent", "subclass", "AppYear", "app", "lag(AppYear)"
))


> data
# A tibble: 10 x 3
  Patent  subclass AppYear
   <chr>   <chr>      <int>
 1 4683202 435/91.2    1985
 2 4683195 435/91.2    1986
 3 4800159 435/91.2    1986
 4 4965188 435/91.2    1987
 5 4994368 435/91.2    1987
 6 5328824 435/91.2    1987
 7 4879214 435/91.2    1988
 8 4921794 435/91.2    1988
 9 4983728 435/91.2    1990
10 4994372 435/91.2    1990
```

Firstly, I need to get the rolling count of distinct years 'app'. Secondly, I need to create the lag of the distinct years 'lag(AppYear)', which in case the previous year(s) is the same will fetch the line with year-1.

**Desired Output**

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
   Patent  subclass AppYear   app `lag(AppYear)`
   <chr>   <chr>      <int> <int>          <int>
 1 4683202 435/91.2    1985     1             NA
 2 4683195 435/91.2    1986     2           1985
 3 4800159 435/91.2    1986     2           1985
 4 4965188 435/91.2    1987     3           1986
 5 4994368 435/91.2    1987     3           1986
 6 5328824 435/91.2    1987     3           1986
 7 4879214 435/91.2    1988     4           1987
 8 4921794 435/91.2    1988     4           1987
 9 4983728 435/91.2    1990     5           1988
10 4994372 435/91.2    1990     5           1988
```

**Edit** The whole dataset includes many subclasses thus I need to group first by `subclass`. The data is now sorted in this way:

```
data <- data %>% 
  select(Patent, subclass, AppYear) %>% 
  arrange(AppYear,Patent) %>% 
  group_by(subclass) %>% 
  mutate(app = 1:n(), lag(AppYear))
```

.

```
structure(list(Patent = c("4683202", "4683195", "4800159", "4965188", 
"4994368", "5328824", "4879214", "4921794", "4983728", "4994372", 
"5066584", "5075216", "5091310", "5093245", "5132215", "5185243", 
"5409818", "5409818", "6107023", "4994370", "5001050", "5023171", 
"5035996", "5035996", "5043272", "5045450", "5055393", "5085983", 
"5106729", "5106729"), subclass = c("435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", 
"435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", 
"435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", 
"435/91.2", "435/91.21", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", 
"435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.21", "435/91.2", 
"435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.21"), 
    AppYear = c(1985L, 1986L, 1986L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1988L, 
    1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 
    1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 
    1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L), app = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 
    17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 2L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
    3L), `lag(AppYear)` = c(NA, 1985L, 1986L, 1986L, 1987L, 1987L, 
    1987L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 
    1988L, NA, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1988L, 
    1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), .Names = c("Patent", "subclass", "AppYear", "app", "lag(AppYear)"
))
```

I have tried to get `app` using many approaches such as `cumsum(1:length(AppYear))` but could not find a successful answer.

Comment: ```data %>% mutate(app=group_indices(.,AppYear))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` version. The gnarly part is a self-join to allow for a look-up table to do the lag year.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df1)

setorder(dt, AppYear, Patent)
dt[, app := rleid(AppYear), by = .(subclass)]

dt[unique(dt[, .(lagging_year = shift(AppYear)
                 ,lagging_app = shift(app) + 1), by = subclass])
   , on = .(subclass 
            ,app = lagging_app )
   , lag_year := lagging_year]

dt

     Patent  subclass AppYear app lag_year
 1: 4683202  435/91.2    1985   1       NA
 2: 4683195  435/91.2    1986   2     1985
 3: 4800159  435/91.2    1986   2     1985
 4: 4965188  435/91.2    1987   3     1986
 5: 4994368  435/91.2    1987   3     1986
 6: 5328824  435/91.2    1987   3     1986
 7: 4879214  435/91.2    1988   4     1987
 8: 4921794  435/91.2    1988   4     1987
 9: 4983728  435/91.2    1988   4     1987
10: 4994372  435/91.2    1988   4     1987
#total of 30 rows.
```

Here's largely the equivalent of @M-M's answer. Note the `.GRP` keeps counting up so it's not 100% equivalent. The first `subclass` that is 435/91.21 has an `app` of 5 here instead of 1 in the other solutions.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df1)
setorder(dt, AppYear, Patent)
dt[, `:=` (app = .GRP, app_cnt = .N), by = .( AppYear, subclass)]

dt[, lag_year := rep(shift(unique(AppYear)), unique(app_cnt)), by = .(subclass)]
dt[, app_cnt := NULL]

dt
```

And here's the performance:

```
Unit: milliseconds
              expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
         M_M_dplyr 6.5839 6.85235 7.442658 6.94440 7.26040 23.0357   100
      cole_dt_join 6.0260 6.27025 6.616121 6.44040 6.84965  8.3686   100
       cole_dt_rep 3.0404 3.15575 3.435112 3.26355 3.76085  4.7526   100
 cole_dt_rep_rleid 3.4116 3.59275 3.911844 3.68695 4.01000 10.3520   100
```

Data and functions:

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- structure(list(Patent = c("4683202", "4683195", "4800159", "4965188", 
                                "4994368", "5328824", "4879214", "4921794", "4983728", "4994372", 
                                "5066584", "5075216", "5091310", "5093245", "5132215", "5185243", 
                                "5409818", "5409818", "6107023", "4994370", "5001050", "5023171", 
                                "5035996", "5035996", "5043272", "5045450", "5055393", "5085983", 
                                "5106729", "5106729"), subclass = c("435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", 
                                                                    "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", 
                                                                    "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", 
                                                                    "435/91.2", "435/91.21", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", 
                                                                    "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.21", "435/91.2", 
                                                                    "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.21"), 
                     AppYear = c(1985L, 1986L, 1986L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1988L, 
                                 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 
                                 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 
                                 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L)
)
                , class = "data.frame"
                , row.names = c(NA, 
                                -30L)
                , .Names = c("Patent", "subclass", "AppYear"))


# dt join method ----------------------------------------------------------

dt <- as.data.table(df1)

setorder(dt, AppYear, Patent)
dt[, app := rleid(AppYear), by = .(subclass)]

dt[unique(dt[, .(lagging_year = shift(AppYear)
                 ,lagging_app = shift(app) + 1), by = subclass])
   , on = .(subclass 
            ,app = lagging_app )
   , lag_year := lagging_year]

dt

# dt rep rleid method -----------------------------------------------------------

dt <- as.data.table(df1)
setorder(dt, AppYear, Patent)
dt[, app := rleid(AppYear), by = .(subclass)]
dt[, app_cnt := .N, by = .( AppYear, subclass)]

dt[, lag_year := rep(shift(unique(AppYear)), unique(app_cnt)), by = .(subclass)]
dt[, app_cnt := NULL]

dt

# dt rep and .GRP ---------------------------------------------------------

dt <- as.data.table(df1)
setorder(dt, AppYear, Patent)

dt[, `:=` (app = .GRP, app_cnt = .N), by = .( AppYear, subclass)]

dt[, lag_year := rep(shift(unique(AppYear)), unique(app_cnt)), by = .(subclass)]
dt[, app_cnt := NULL]

dt


# benchmarks --------------------------------------------------------------

microbenchmark(M_M_dplyr = {
  df1 %>% 
    arrange(AppYear, Patent) %>%
    group_by(subclass) %>% 
    group_map(~mutate(.,app=group_indices(.,AppYear),
                      lag_year = rep(lag(unique(.$AppYear)), count_(., "AppYear")$n)), 
              keep = T) %>% 
    bind_rows() %>% 
    arrange(AppYear, Patent)
}
, cole_dt_join = {
  dt <- as.data.table(df1)

  setorder(dt, AppYear, Patent)
  dt[, app := rleid(AppYear), by = .(subclass)]

  dt[unique(dt[, .(lagging_year = shift(AppYear)
                   ,lagging_app = shift(app) + 1), by = subclass])
     , on = .(subclass 
              ,app = lagging_app )
     , lag_year := lagging_year]
}
,cole_dt_rep = {
  dt <- as.data.table(df1)

  setorder(dt, AppYear, Patent)

  dt[, `:=` (app = .GRP, app_cnt = .N), by = .( AppYear, subclass)]

  dt[, lag_year := rep(shift(unique(AppYear)), unique(app_cnt)), by = .(subclass)]
  dt[, app_cnt := NULL]
}
,cole_dt_rep_rleid = {
  dt <- as.data.table(df1)

  dt[, app := rleid(AppYear), by = .(subclass)]
  dt[, app_cnt := .N, by = .( AppYear, subclass)]

  dt[, lag_year := rep(shift(unique(AppYear)), unique(app_cnt)), by = .(subclass)]
  dt[, app_cnt := NULL]
}
)
```

Comment: Nice one. Joining is what I tried first, but I think using `rep` with `.N`  (similar to what I have in dplyr) would be faster. Cheers. +1

Comment: I had the ```rep``` at first but thought it was too similar :). I've edited it to include it. You were right, using ```rep``` is faster.

Comment: Well I think comparing the third solution with the two others is not a robust one as it is not addressing the whole problem.

Comment: Did OP want the app to restart at 1 for the different subclasses? There's no example output for that. It's pretty robust but I'll add another timing to have it restart at 1 later today for a more accurate comparison.

Comment: See edit. I put ```dplyr``` in the best light by not having to ```select(Patent, subclass, AppYear)``` while still converting the ```df1``` to a ```data.table``` for the benchmark.  The equivalent ```data.table()``` method is still around twice as fast.

Comment: I wasn't arguing that data.table is not faster. Just wanted to make sure your benchmark is precise. In my experience, data.table solutions (if we don't mess them up) are almost always faster than dplyr ones. Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195892/discussion-between-cole-and-m-m).

Comment: Hi @Coli thank you for you response. I added `setorder(dt, AppYear, Patent)` to the `cole_dt_rep_rleid` and it works pretty well. Whereas with the `cole_dt_rep` I get this error: `> dt[, lag_year := rep(shift(unique(AppYear)), unique(app_cnt)), by = .(subclass)]
Error in rep(shift(unique(AppYear)), unique(app_cnt)) : 
  invalid 'times' argument`

Comment: @Amleto, I updated the code with your recommendation. I just ran the entire code at the bottom of my post - I received no errors. You can do ```dt[, .(shift(unique(AppYear)), unique(app_cnt)), by = .(subclass)]``` and see what arguments are going into ```rep()```.

Answer (score 5):

### Update:

*Addressing the follow-up question about a df with multiple groups of `subclass`.*

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  select(Patent, subclass, AppYear) %>% 
  arrange(AppYear, Patent) %>%
  group_by(subclass) %>% 
  group_map(~mutate(.,app=group_indices(.,AppYear),
                    lag_year = rep(lag(unique(.$AppYear)), count_(., "AppYear")$n)), 
            keep = T) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  arrange(AppYear, Patent) 

#> # A tibble: 30 x 5
#>    Patent  subclass AppYear   app lag_year
#>    <chr>   <chr>      <int> <int>    <int>
#>  1 4683202 435/91.2    1985     1       NA
#>  2 4683195 435/91.2    1986     2     1985
#>  3 4800159 435/91.2    1986     2     1985
#>  4 4965188 435/91.2    1987     3     1986
#>  5 4994368 435/91.2    1987     3     1986
#>  6 5328824 435/91.2    1987     3     1986
#>  7 4879214 435/91.2    1988     4     1987
#>  8 4921794 435/91.2    1988     4     1987
#>  9 4983728 435/91.2    1988     4     1987
#> 10 4994372 435/91.2    1988     4     1987
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```

***N.B.*** I am using the data provided by OP under *Edit* section of the question.

---

---

### Original Answer:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  arrange(AppYear, Patent) %>%
  mutate(app = group_indices(.,AppYear), 
        lag_year = rep(lag(unique(.$AppYear)), count_(., "AppYear")$n))

#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    Patent  subclass AppYear   app lag_year
#>    <chr>   <chr>      <int> <int>    <int>
#>  1 4683202 435/91.2    1985     1       NA
#>  2 4683195 435/91.2    1986     2     1985
#>  3 4800159 435/91.2    1986     2     1985
#>  4 4965188 435/91.2    1987     3     1986
#>  5 4994368 435/91.2    1987     3     1986
#>  6 5328824 435/91.2    1987     3     1986
#>  7 4879214 435/91.2    1988     4     1987
#>  8 4921794 435/91.2    1988     4     1987
#>  9 4983728 435/91.2    1990     5     1988
#> 10 4994372 435/91.2    1990     5     1988
```

***Data:***

```r
df1 <- structure(list(Patent=c("4683202", "4683195", "4800159", "4965188", 
                      "4994368", "5328824", "4879214", "4921794", "4983728", "4994372"), 
                 subclass=c("435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2",
                      "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2", "435/91.2"), 
                 AppYear=c(1985L, 1986L, 1986L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1988L, 
                      1988L, 1990L, 1990L)), 
                 row.names=c(NA, -10L), 
                 class=c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt answer. There is only one caveat. In my dataset I have different subclasses that is why I initially used `group_by(subclass)` . I reported here a section with only one subclass to simplify the dataset, although I am looking for a solution which possibly group by subclass.

Comment: @Amleto Can you share a desired output for a example dataset with two subclasses?